# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I have upgraded my application from Angular 2 to Angular 6 version. ng build --prod is building application successfully. I am able to login into my application and 50% functionality is working perfectly where some of the options are not working and throwing below exception:

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: **Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known native property** ("   <form class="form-inline" [ERROR ->][formGroup]="xSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  "): a@5:34

**Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known native property** ("abel> <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" [(ngModel)]="model.xxx" [ERROR ->][formControl]="xSearchForm.find('yyy')" id="xxx" />  "): a@13:93

I am importing FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts and added these imports in NgModule imports also.

Comment: Your component is not in the `declarations` of your module perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your AppModule or in the module where your component is declared.

```
  import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  ... 
  ...

  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
```

`ReactiveFormsModule` is defined in `@angular/forms`

Comment: Yes I am already importing it, but still getting same issue.